# Why does my Fibonacci series using Ruby's inject doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, fibonacci

This is embarrassing, I don't get why this line of code isn't returning to me the Fibonnacci series, but instead just a series of ones.

```
(1..5).inject([1]) { |arr, x| x > 1 ? arr << arr.last + arr.last-1 : arr << 1; arr }
```

The code above is supposed to find the 1st six numbers in the series.

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you as always.

Comment: Incidentally, Do you guys think it's easier than this by doing it recursively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arr.last-1 doesnt work, try  arr[-2] instead:

```
p (1..5).inject([1]) { |arr, x| x > 1 ? arr << arr.last + arr[-2] : arr << 1 }
#=>[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

-edit-
btw you don't need that ;arr at the end, << returns the array by default

Comment: Cool! How did I not see it !? 
Thanks!

Comment: I'll give this point to you since you were the first to answer, (and thanks for letting me know I don't need the ; arr at the end)
Thank you sir!

Comment: I assume your main language of choice is C or C++

Answer (score 3):

`arr.last-1` doesn't give you the second-to-last element of the array. It takes the last element and just subtracts one from it.

You want something like `arr[arr.length - 2]` or the fancy Ruby shortcut `arr[-2]`.

Comment: Thank you !
Such a Rookie Mistake.. Your solution is the same as the first guy, But thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Ruby, so this may be completely off, but it seems like this might be your culprit:

```
arr.last + arr.last-1
```

I don't think that this means "the last array element plus the element before it," but rather

```
arr.last + (arr.last)-1
```

Note that if you seed the array with 1, this would give you back 1 + 1 - 1 = 1, which means that your terms always evaluate to one, which probably isn't what you want.

Let me know if this is totally off, and hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had something to do with how I was using the last method.

Answer (score 2):

First off let's not forget the series actually starts with 0 and there is a far easier way to do this:

```
1.9.2-p290 :009 > 4.times.inject([0,1]) {|s| s + [s[-1] + s[-2]]}
 => [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Enjoy!

Comment: You solution is pretty cool. very clean, I like it, thanks for your contribution Wes!

Answer (score 2):

And yet another way in case you really like to use `inject` :)

```
(1..20).inject( [0, 1] ) { | fib | fib << fib.last(2).inject(:+) }
=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946]
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way:

```
(1..10).inject( [0, 1] ) { |sum| sum << sum.last(2).sum }
=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```